# Is there Constant Contact integration for CiviCRM in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, extension

I don't see Constant Contact on the list of Extensions.

Answer (score 2):

There's an extension to sync them here: https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.sync.constantcontact

Comment: Thanks, Jon G. Do you have any personal experience with it?

Comment: I did, a long time ago!  I haven't tried it recently.  With Mosaico 2 in beta now, more and more folks are using that extension to build CiviMail templates, which eliminates the reason most folks use Constant Contact.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of, all of the organizations we work with use CiviMail or MailChimp. But I am sure it can be created if you are willing to provide the funding :-)