# Is there Constant Contact integration for CiviCRM in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

I am implementing CiviCRM on a Joomla site and would like to integrate the contacts to Constant Contact.  Is there an extension or integration that I can use to integrate Constant Contact with my Joomla CiviCRM instance?

Answer (score 1):

This [extension](https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.sync.constantcontact) was flagged as an option in this other [Q+A](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18246/is-there-constant-contact-integration-for-civicrm-in-wordpress)

Comment: I see that you flagged this with a post about WordPress and Constant Contact.  The site I am building is Joomla and am looking to see if there is a way to integrate the contacts between the two.

Comment: Hi Margaret - the extension i linked you to is for Civi and Constant Contact as I assumed it was your civi contacts that matter here more than the CMS

Comment: as the extension is for civicrm it should be CMS agnostic unless it says otherwise (which it doesn't).

Comment: I see palante made some notes about it here https://redmine.palantetech.coop/projects/commons/wiki/Constant_Contact_sync_for_CiviCRM